# Windows update: "Some update files aren't signed correctly." How to find out which?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-preview

Using Windows 10 build 10586, I get the following error

> Some update files aren't signed correctly.
>
> Error code: (0x800b0109)

When it tries to download the new 11082 build.

I have checked the certificate stores and they seemed okay (I might have untrusted some CAs myself but none are MS-related.)

I have seen [two](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-10-insider-preview-11082-update-files/9b6cd8ea-8c7f-4e7e-81b5-e1d0a0fd5ed4) [threads](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-insider-preview-11082-update-files/6d635d31-60e9-473a-99de-db0a54da23e1) on MS community, but they do not offer any real solution.

I am happy to troubleshoot this myself, but I cannot find relevent info in the logs. I have tried CBS and DISM logs. No mention of this error...

Comment: Based on how new the build is I am going to guess there isn't actually a resolution.

Comment: can you now update to Build 11102?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Nope... it sees the update but gives the same error when trying to download it. I'll probably grab the ISO and update that way.

Comment: ok, do this ISO upgrade, wait for the next Build and look if you can update to this build.

Comment: ok, Microsoft released a new Insider Build 14251 . Have you made the ISO upgrade to the 11102 and see this Build?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Not yet :( Been busy with other stuff, but I'll try it this weekend. Since my build got stuck on this version, I am beginning to like it as it does not suddenly restart itself to install a new OS. My only concern is with security updates ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the media creator to "upgrade" my system which returned it to build 10586. Windows update was then able to download and install the 14251 build without any problem.

It seems there must have been some kind of corruption.